# Closed form for this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\, e^{-x^{2}-\frac{b^{2}}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How would you evaluate this integral?
\begin{equation}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\, e^{-x^{2}-\frac{b^{2}}{x}}\end{equation}
It reminds me of the form of a modified Bessel function of the second kind, but is slightly different because of the $x^{2}$ term. I can series expand it in terms of a sum of Gamma functions, but I don't know what that sum converges to.

Comment: I do not consider hypergeometric functions to be closed forms, but merely alternative notations. Nevertheless, perhaps [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/txTDY.jpg) might prove helpful when coupled with [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov) in the hands of a knowledgeable person.

Comment: Thanks Lucian, I've gotten that result before and wasn't really satisfied with it either. It comes about just by doing a series expansion after re writing the integrand a bit. Thank you for the references though.

Comment: Are you sure about that infinite sum?  It looks like you expanded
$e^{-b^2/x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-b^2/x)^n/n!$ and integrated
termwise using the formula for $\int_0^\infty x^s e^{-x^2} dx$,
but that formula is not valid for $s \leq -1$ (corresponding to $n \geq 1$)
because the integral diverges.

Comment: ... and it doesn't seem to work numerically: for $b=1$ the integral is
well below $1$ but the sum is $>1$ (**gp** says 
**intnum(x=.01,10^3,exp(-x^2-1/x)/sqrt(x))** is about $0.163$ while
**(1/4) * suminf(n=0,(-1)^n*gamma(1/4-n/2)/n!)** is about $1.396$).

Comment: Assuming the integral cannot be obtained in closed form, is there
something specific you want to know about it, like behavior for
small, large, or complex $b$?

Comment: I expanded it termwise, but only after a few changes of variables so that it was in the form of a Gamma function. I actually do need it in closed form more or less because I have a few more operators to apply to it after I've obtained it.

Comment: Well the change of variable $x^2=u$ already makes each term
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-b^2/x)^n/n!$ look like a Gamma function;
but again the integrals don't converge for $n>0$, and the sum
$\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} b^{2n} \Gamma(\frac14-\frac{n}2)$
that one gets by imagining that the Gamma integral works also for $n>0$
does converge but doesn't agree with the integral.

Comment: I understand that closed form is ideal, but most definite integrals 
simply don't have such an expression :-( and this seems to be one of them.

Comment: I appreciate the discussion at least Noam, and I think you're right about the expansion after all. I probably overlooked convergence issues when deriving it. Maybe there is a way around this integral altogether in what I'm working on.

Comment: You can get a closed form in terms of the hypergeomtric function form by using Maple.

Answer (score 6):

I rewrite the integral in the form
$$
I=\tfrac{1}{2}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-t^2}\frac{e^{-b^2/|t|}}{\sqrt{|t|}}dt.
$$
With the help of Fourier transform 
$$
\widehat{f}(x)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)e^{-itx}dt
$$
the Parseval indentity
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt=\tfrac{1}{2\pi}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\widehat{f}(x)\overline{\widehat{g}(x)}dx
$$
and the pairs
$$
e^{-t^2}\leftrightarrow \sqrt{\pi}e^{-x^2/4}
$$
$$
\frac{e^{-b^2/|t|}}{\sqrt{|t|}}\leftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{|x|}}e^{-b\sqrt{2|x|}}\left(\cos\left(b\sqrt{2|x|}\right)-\sin\left(b\sqrt{2|x|}\right)\right)\textrm{, }b>0
$$
we get
$$
I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int^{+\infty}_{0}\frac{\cos\left(b\sqrt{2x}\right)-\sin\left(b\sqrt{2x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-x^2/4-b\sqrt{2x}}dx
$$
Setting $x=w^2/2$ and then $w=s/b$, we arive to
$$
I=\int^{+\infty}_{0}\exp\left(-w^4/16-bw\right)(\cos(bw)-\sin(bw))dw=
$$
$$
=b^{-1}\int^{+\infty}_{0}\exp\left(-\frac{s^4}{16b^4}\right)e^{-s}(\cos s-\sin s)ds\tag 1
$$
But
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{0}\exp\left(-\frac{s^4}{16b^4}\right)s^kds=2^{k-1}b^{k+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{4}\right)\textrm{, for }k=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
Hence using the Taylor expansions of $e^{-s}\cos s$ and $e^{-s}\sin s$:
$$
I=\tfrac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(-1)^k2^{3k/2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{4}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{4}\right)\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{4}\right)\frac{b^{k}}{k!}=
$$
$$
=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(-1)^k2^{3k/2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi (k+1)}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{4}\right)\frac{b^{k}}{k!}=\ldots
$$
$$
=2\Gamma(\tfrac{5}{4})\cdot {}_0F_2\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{4};-\tfrac{b^4}{4}\right)-2b\sqrt{\pi}\cdot {}_0F_2\left(\tfrac{3}{4},\tfrac{5}{4};-\tfrac{b^4}{4}\right)+2b^2\Gamma(\tfrac{3}{4})\cdot {}_0F_2\left(\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{5}{4};-\tfrac{b^4}{4}\right)
$$
Another way is to write (1) as
$$
I=\left(1-i\right)I_0(2(1+i)b)+(1+i)I_0\left(2(1-i)b\right),\tag 2
$$
where
$$
I_0(z)=\int^{+\infty}_{0}\exp\left(-s^4\right)e^{-zs}ds\tag 3
$$